# Make RadioButton Equal Textbox Amount MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

In my MVC 3 project, I have certain radio button representing certain amounts and I want a radio button to represent Custom Amount. Next to the radio button will be a textbox to retrieve the custom amount.

At the moment I have this:

```
Custom Amount @Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", "115" , true) @Html.TextBox("InvoiceAmount")
```

But then obviously the InvoiceAmount is set to 115, so how would I put the textbox's value in place of that 115?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the textbox and check to see if it has a value when your form is submitted. Then you would not need a "radio button" for custom amount.

I may not be entirely sure of your intent here though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using strongly typed view and view models (which is what I would recommend you):

```
@Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", Model.InvoiceAmount, true)
```

if not:

```
@Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", ViewData["InvoiceAmount"] ?? "0", true)
```

Also notice that having two input elements with the same name (`InvoiceAmount`) inside your form is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I am using strongly typed views. So how would the textbox amount fit into this?

Comment: @Amy, normally you could pass any object as second argument to the RadioButton helper.